# Loop a foreach json loop in another foreach json loop

Tags: php

I'm at a 24 hour hackathon trying to solve this so, excuse if it's a little rushed.

1st for each loop works fine, I'm getting a list of categories from this url

```
https://dev.xola.com/api/categories
```

I grab the list with this

```
$fullurl = "https://dev.xola.com/api/categories"; 
$string .= file_get_contents($fullurl); // get json content
$json_a = json_decode($string, true); //json decoder
```

then loop it with this

```
<?
foreach($json_a as $v)
{?>
echo $v ?}>
```

Now with the second for each look, I want to grab the items from this url

```
https://dev.xola.com/api/experiences
```

that match the category from the last url

```
so samething 
$fullurl = "https://dev.xola.com/api/categories"; 
$string .= file_get_contents($fullurl); // get json content
$json_b = json_decode($string, true); //json decoder
```

here's the complete loop I tried

```
 <?
 $i=0;
foreach($json_a as $v)
```

$i++
    {?>
    echo $v ?

```
 foreach($json_b as $x){?>
 if($v==$x):   
 echo $v
 endif;
 ?>

}?>
```

Comment: There are some typo mistakes please correct them first

Comment: `$1=0;`? PHP variables can't start with a number.

Comment: Why do you contatenate `$string .= file_get_contents($fullurl)`? If you concatenate 2 strings with json-stringified data - you won't be able to parse result as json.

Comment: The diffrent urls does not have the same format. The latter one has Data and then Category in it. Therefore the comparision seem faulty. Then you should not concatenate the $string because then you're comparing the string with itself. (first elements of $json_b is the same elements as $json_a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a `$result` array with only the data that had the categories early acquired:

```
<?php
$categories_url = "https://dev.xola.com/api/categories";
$data = file_get_contents($categories_url);
$categories = json_decode($data, true);

$experiences_url = "https://dev.xola.com/api/experiences";
$data = file_get_contents($experiences_url);
$experiences = json_decode($data, true);
$result = array();
foreach ($experiences['data'] as $experience)
{
    if (in_array($experience['category'], $categories))
    {
        $result[] = $experience;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

And you can easily read the result with:

```
foreach ($result as $item)
{
    echo $item['category'], "\n";
    echo $item['desc'], "\n";
    //... other data available ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data structure of the experiences JSON is not the same as the categories JSON, therefore `if($v==$x)` will never match. If you want to find all results in experiences with a category from the categories url you can do the following:

```
<?

    $BASE_URL = 'https://dev.xola.com/api/';

    $categories = json_decode(file_get_contents($BASE_URL . 'categories'));
    $experiences = json_decode(file_get_contents($BASE_URL . 'experiences'));
    $matches = array();

    foreach( $categories as $category ) {

        foreach( $experiences->data as $experience ) {

            if( $experience->category === $category ) {

                $matches[] = $experience;
            }

        }

    }

?>
<? foreach( $matches as $match ) : ?>
    <? echo $match->category; ?><br>
<? endforeach; ?>
```